# Restrict Times in JQuery UI Datepicker Timepicker Add-on

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-timepicker

I'm using [Trent Richardsons Timepicker](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/) add-on for the JQuery Datepicker and I need to be able to restrict the times that our user can pick.

My code so far:

```
$('.datepicker').datetimepicker({
    showOn: "both",
    buttonImage: "/images/icons/cal-clock-icon-16x16.png",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    hourMin: 8,
    hourMax: 16,
    stepMinute: 15,
    minuteGrid: 15,
    addSliderAccess: true,
    sliderAccessArgs: {touchonly: false},
    altField: "#testTime",
    altFieldTimeOnly: false,
    altFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    altTimeFormat : "HH:mm:ss",
    dateFormat: "D, d MM yy",
    timeFormat: "hh:mmtt"
});
```

So I have the min and max hours, and I have it jumping in 15 minute intervals as need be, but there are certain specific minutes I don't want them to book. So for example I don't want them selecting 8:15, 8:45, 9:15, 9:45, 10:00, 10:15, etc Does anyone know how I might be able to code this?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Trent [debated adding this feature a while ago](http://trentrichardson.com/2013/02/03/jquery-timepicker-1-2-works-with-jqueryui-1-10/), but then didn't proceed any further.

Jon Thornton's [Timepicker](http://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/) plugin has a `DisableTimeRanges` option if that helps.